# How to find boundary data for cities in Utah

Tags: data, united-states, boundaries

I'm working on a brand new project where I need boundary data for various cities in Utah. Salt Lake City was easy since their data is available for [public download](http://gis.slcgov.opendata.arcgis.com/). The other cities? Not so much. Apparently this information is available as [US Census data](https://www.census.gov/cgi-bin/geo/shapefiles2014/main) but I'm having a hard time parsing out the boundary data within. I'm more of a web developer so, I've never been in the position of tracking down the data itself. Annoyingly, a lot of cities in Utah have this information available as [pdf download](http://www.cedarcity.org/128/Maps) but I need the lat long city boundaries to build polygons in a web map. Can any of you more experienced cartographers help me?

Comment: The Census Bureau shapefile you'd want is the one for "Places". In CB terminology, this includes incorporated towns and cities, as well as some unincorporated population centers: http://www.census.gov/geo/reference/gtc/gtc_place.html. For states that have minor civil divisions (Utah's not one of them), you could also look at the County Subdivisions file: http://www.census.gov/geo/reference/gtc/gtc_cousub.html

Comment: Yeah, I wanted the data itself.....I hate working with raster shapefiles....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Provo GIS Office was very helpful! Turns out the state of Utah keeps all this info for easy download on their website!

http://gis.utah.gov/data/boundaries/citycountystate/